# How can I call a dynamically named file?

Tags: java

Right now I have

```
System.out.println("Enter Username!");
    tring username = name.nextLine();
    String userNameScore = username +"_scores"+ ".txt";
    File NameScore = new File("/Users/macbook/NetBeansProjects/MathQuiz/UserScores/" + userNameScore);
```

How can I call on this created file from another JavaClass?

Comment: You just pass around your reference. If the other class needs a `File`, it should demand it in its constructor or method as a parameter. And the caller can then pass it over. Alternatively the current class can also expose it via a getter or similar, but for that it has to be stored as a field first.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is by using a `getter` method in your class with the file. At the bottom of the class that generates the file put :

```
//Allows other classes to access file created
public File getFile(){
   return this.NameScore;
}
```

In your other classes, where you want to refer to the file be sure to create an instance of the class first to be able to access the method which returns the file name in the class.

```
className name = new className();
```

Then to invoke the method to access the file, create a file object in the class you want to access it from and assign the object like so :

`File file = name.getFile();`

Here you are referencing the instance of the class with the file and invoking the `get` method which will return the file.

Altogether it will look like:

--class with the file code--

```
public class fileGen
{
    //Your code here

    File file = new File("test.txt");

    //Setting the getter method
    public File getFile(){
        return this.file;
    }

}
```

--Class you want to reference the file from--

```
//As I named my class fileGen
fileGen filee = new fileGen();

//Assigning file object to instance of class invoking the get method to be able to access the file
File fil = filee.getFile();
```